# Skip match if in specific content

Tags: php, regex

I need to match a given word in a text, except when found in a specific sentence.

So far i created the following regex:

```regex
(?!^)\G(?:['"][a-z0-9:\/._-]+example.com[a-z0-9:\/._-]+['"])(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|((?:\b|[_])elementor)(?:\b|[_])
```

So if the word elementor is found into a 'http://example.com/content/elementor' this should not match.

Here's a regex tester https://regex101.com/r/NMOvfx/1/

Comment: Maybe `https?:\/\/[^\s'"]*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<![^\W_])(elementor)(?![^\W_])`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this appear to work perfectly !  can you post your solution so i can accept it?

Comment: Done, see below.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew By the way, is there any way to add a second (*SKIP)(*FAIL) criteria to the patter? e.g. so it ignore if in sentence font-family:     https://regex101.com/r/7M9nce/3

Comment: The point is to use a group: `(?:exclude1|exclude2)(*SKIP)(*F)|match_me_instead`

Comment: Yep, you are correct, tried that at https://regex101.com/r/7M9nce/4 but does not appear to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201253/discussion-between-kole23-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
'~https?://[^\s'"]*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<![^\W_])(elementor)(?![^\W_])~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7M9nce/2)

**Details**

- `https?://` - `https://` or  `http://`
- `[^\s'"]*` - 0 or more chars other than whitespace, `'` or `"`
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` - the current match is discarded and the next match is searched for from the failed match end
- `|` - or
- `(?<![^\W_])` - a position not preceded with a word or `_` char
- `(elementor)` - Group 1: word `elementor`
- `(?![^\W_])` - the position not followed with a word or `_` char.